# how do I create a new branch that inherits the parent remotes

Tags: git

I have a local repository with a tracked remote branch. I want to create a new branch off that branch that inherits the remotes so I can push the new branch to the remote.

1. while on the tracked local branch which we want in the new branch but do not want to push.

   git checkout -b myNewBranch
2. push the branch to the remote

   git push -u RemoteRepo myNewBranch

Currently I have to first set the remote on the new branch to the remote repo.

Comment: Googler, you may want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030327/git-create-branch-and-inherit-upstream-of-current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your question phrasing a bit confusing, but let's see if this is correct.

1. You have a repo `repo` cloned from some origin machine `O`.
2. In `repo`, you have a local branch `b` that is tracking `origin/b`, i.e., a branch named `b` on `O`.  You're on it (`git checkout b`).
3. You now want to create a new branch, `nb`.  There is no branch `nb` on `O`.
4. You want `nb` to track the non-existent branch `origin/nb`.

That last step is not possible (yet) because `origin/nb` does not exist yet.  You must create it first (as in your `git push -u` command above).  Pushing with `-u` will create `nb` on `O` and also (locally) create `origin/nb` and set the upstream branch for `nb` to `origin/nb`.

Note that if you try to set the upstream:

```
$ git checkout -b nb
... optionally, add various commits here ...
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/nb
```

you'll get an error:

```
error: the requested upstream branch 'origin/nb' does not exist
hint: 
hint: If you are planning on basing your work on an upstream
hint: branch that already exists at the remote, you may need to
hint: run "git fetch" to retrieve it.
hint: 
hint: If you are planning to push out a new local branch that
hint: will track its remote counterpart, you may want to use
hint: "git push -u" to set the upstream config as you push.
```

So instead you must do exactly what you suggested above, and is shown in the "hint"s:

```
$ git checkout -b nb
... optionally, add various commits here ...
$ git push -u origin nb
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 633 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]
 * [new branch]      nb -> nb
Branch nb set up to track remote branch nb from origin.
```

Comment: That is all correct. The problem is when I do git push -u for origin/nb the nb branch does not have origin set yet, even though origin was set for origin/b.

Comment: bah I just did a test and it worked. Something must of been wrong with the other persons repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no uncommitted changes (check with `git status`), just check out the remote branch by specifying the starting point at 2nd argument:

```
git checkout -b mybranch remote/rembranch
```

This will create the branch `mybranch`, starting from `remote/rembranch`.

Comment: In our case the local branch has local commits we want in the new branch, so just basing it off the remote will not work.

Comment: OK, so you need to rebase your branch on the remote: simply do `git rebase remote/branch` from your local branch