# git create branch and inherit upstream of current

Tags: git

I use the following to create a new local branch `foo`

```
git checkout --track -b foo
```

but when it is created, the `.git/config` entry looks like this

```
[branch "foo"]
    remote = .
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

which is only half correct because the `remote` has not been set to track the remote of the original branch (which is called `upstream` in my case. I use `remote.pushdefault` so that I pull from `upstream` and push to `origin`).

I've also tried using `git branch` directly (after creating it), e.g. with

```
git branch -u upstream/master foo
```

and that seems to work, but it means I need to type the `upstream/master` part manually every time (which is actually dynamic... this is the trivial case).

Is there a command to effectively say "set the upstream to the current upstream"?

My attempts to update it, e.g. with

```
git branch -u `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}` foo
```

result in `fatal: branch 'foo' does not exist`.

**UPDATE** this hack seems to work, but it's ugly, so I'd still like something cleaner

```
[alias]
        cut = "!f() { UPSTREAM=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}`; git checkout -b $1 $UPSTREAM; git config branch.$1.pushremote origin; }; f"
```

(the second part is needed for magit)

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems I cooked up an alias to do this

```
[alias]
    cut = "!f() { UPSTREAM=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic-full-name @{u}`; git checkout -b $1 $UPSTREAM; git config branch.$1.pushremote origin; }; f"
```

the second part is for magit, so you can drop `git config branch.$1.pushremote origin;` if you don't use it.